# CentOS: set locale for user

Tags: linux, centos, bash, localization

Maybe i don't understand about locales...  But could You explain me:

If I set locale using localectl:

```
localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

I see in localectl output after this:

```
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: us
```

The system locale now is en_US.UTF-8

But in `locale` output I still see this:

```
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

**Is only one way to set user's locale - export it or add into .bash_profile file to save after rebooting?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do below:

Do below for global changes

```
/etc/default/locale – on Ubuntu/Debian
/etc/locale.conf – on CentOS/RHEL
```

For particular user, edit file `~/.bash_profile` by adding:

```
LANG="<your selection>"
export LANG
```

Answer (score 1):

Set System Locale:

```
$ localectl set-locale LANG=ja_JP.utf8
```

Reboot